# All types for given client SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Okay so I have a database setup like this:

```
Client {Clientt#, FirstName, LastName, Email, city};
RType {TName, Price, TRooms};
Location {Confirm#, Arrival, Departure, Origin, Client# (references Guest), Type (references RoomType)}
```

I need to pretty much create SQL statement that gives me a list of ALL clients who have been in ALL Types.

I wrote this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT Client#, FirstName, LastName, Type
FROM Client, Location
WHERE Client.Client# = Location.Client# and Location.Type = (select count(DISTINCT TName) from RType);
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using the `having` clause.  The question is:  what clients have the same number of locations as in the RType table?  This assumes that all Location.Types are in this table.

```
SELECT Client#
FROM Location l
group by Client#
having count(distinct l.type) = (select count(DISTINCT TName) from RType)
```

You can join in the additional information from Client, if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT Client#, FirstName, LastName, Type
FROM Client, Location
WHERE Client.Client# = Location.Client# and 
Location.Type IN (select DISTINCT TName from RType)
```

Answer (score 0):

That COUNT function is returning a count of how many types you have in there, so unless Location.Type = 4, that's not going to work. Either remove the COUNT or just join the tables like below:

```
SELECT t1.Client#, t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t2.Type
FROM Client t1
    INNER JOIN Location t2
        ON t1.Client# = t2.Client#
```